# Send data inside the server from one file to another in node js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, fs

I want to replace an exact variable value in a css file using fs or replace, I have searched enough but I found only about replacing a file in both fs and in replace, below is the code which I have tried to do so, but I want to replace a variable in a css file

```
//to main.css
    var css = selectedTemplatePath + '/css/';
    var mainCss = css + '/main.css';

    var themecolor = new ThemeColor(req.body.color);
    themecolor.color = color;
    themecolor.savecolor(function(err, app ){

        fs.stat(mainCss, function(err, stat){
            var searchApp = {
                _id: appId
            };

            mainCss.findOne(searchApp, function(err, app){
                if(err) return console.error(err);
                replaceThemecolor(app, themecolor);
                console.log("k");
            });



        });
        function replaceThemecolor(themecolor) {
            fs.readFile(mainCss, 'utf-8',
                function(err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        return console.log(err);
                    }

                    var result = data.replace('black', themecolor);

                    fs.writeFile(mainCss, result, 'utf-8', function (err) {
                        if (err) return console.log(err)
                        .success("success");
                        console.log('Success');
                    });
                });
        };
```

Below is the css file and I want to replace color in .background-color with the themecolor I get from the client side

```
.background-color{
        color:black;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like [`css-parser`](https://github.com/reworkcss/css):

```
.background-color{
        color:black;
}

.menu-color{
        color:black;
}
```

Parse, and take the incoming object in-form JSON, find the selector (`background-color`) to the desired vaue properties (`color: black`), replace it with the necessary (`color: timecolor`), and convert back to text:

```
{ "type": "stylesheet",
  "stylesheet": {
    "rules": [
      { /.../
        "selectors": [ ".background-color" ],
        "declarations": [
          { /.../
            "property": "color",
            "value": "black", // => `timecolor`
            /.../
            }
          }
        ], /.../
        }
      },
      { /.../
        "selectors": [ ".menu-color" ],
        "declarations": [
          { /.../
            "property": "color",
            "value": "black",
            /.../
            }
          }
        ], /.../
        }
      },
    ], /.../
}
```

http://iamdustan.com/reworkcss_ast_explorer/#/NYrDzAOEqH/1

Comment: I want to do changes in my js file. I want to change the variable value via the js file not in json

Comment: @adithya What problem with convert JSON back to text CSS?

Comment: I want to include whatever changes in the js file I mentioned above, in the js file that I have tried some coding above. Is it not possible to change the variable value using fs?

Comment: @adithya In `replaceThemecolor` function you parse content of CSS-file (that module to which I gave the link) to JSON; next find and replace selector value; next convert JSON to string and save back to `mainCSS`. Exactly what you need.

Comment: Can you please give an example of doing so